# Turnover Constraint ignores initial weights of Portfolio

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, portfolio

I am trying to perform a standard portfolio optimization, but with a constraint to how much the final weights of the portfolio are allowed to deviate from a set of initial weights. I do this with the `PortfolioAnalytics` package and the following code is a MWE without any errors.

```
# load packages and data
library(quadprog)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
data(edhec)
dat <- edhec[,1:4]

# add initial weights to initial portfolio
funds <- c("Convertible Arbitrage" = 0.4, "CTA Global" = 0.3, "Distressed Securities" = 0.2, "Emerging Markets" = 0.1)
init.portf <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)

# standard constraints & objectives
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="box", min_w=0, min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="return", name="mean") 
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")

# TURNOVER CONSTRAINT (MATTER OF THIS THREAD)
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="turnover", turnover_target=0)

# optimize portfolio
opt.portf <- optimize.portfolio(R=dat, portfolio=init.portf, trace=TRUE, optimize_method="random")

# check the weights of optimized portfolio
print.default(opt.portf$weights)
```

`turnover_target` is `0`, so the output weights should be the same as the input weights `(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)` but instead they are equal weighted `(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)`. Equal weighted are the default initial weights, so somehow it seems like the initial weights I set up aren't recognized. However looking at the documentation of [add.constraint](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/add.constraint) or [turnover_constraint](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/turnover_constraint) doesn't help much. It kinda look's like everything should be working. They way I define the initial weights matches with the documentation of [portfolio.spec](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/portfolio.spec)

Does anyone have an idea why my initial weights are ignored by turnover_constraint?

Comment: If you remove that turnover constraint, what do you get?

Comment: Once I remove it I get a optimized Portfolio without constraints, f.e. with weights like `(0.22, 0.27, 0.51, 0)`. So the turnover constraint itsself has definitely an affect and works as its supposed to work, it's just the initial weights it ignores.

Comment: Maybe the documentation can help: "Note that with the ROI solvers, turnover constraint is currently only supported for the global minimum variance and quadratic utility problems with ROI quadprog plugin." Is that the case ? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf

Comment: I am aware of that, which is why I am using the the `random` solver, with `optimize_method="random"`. Like I said the turnover method itself is working, but somehow I am setting up the initial weights wrong.